# Disabling Message Box for Components from INNO Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to install components (KB932716) and also MS Feature Pack Two. I am trying to add these in a single package and build the installer using Inno Setup.

When I run the set up, components shows up a huge message box which we don't like to show during installation. I tried `\SILENT` and `\VERYSILENT` switches but no use.

Any help on how to disable this message box during installation.

Comment: You need to show your install script, how are you wrapping up the two installers.     The Switches are for the installer you produce, the IMAPI components most likely has different switches for silent operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/quiet` switch for running the component (note the slash is not a backslash).

```
[Run]
Filename: {tmp}\WindowsServer2003-KB932716-v2-x86-ENU.exe; Parameters: /quiet; WorkingDir: {tmp}; Components: ....
```

When in doubt, ask the hotfix the command lines it supports:

`WindowsServer2003-KB932716-v2-x86-ENU.exe /help`

```
...
/help      Displays this message
SETUP MODES
/quiet     Quiet mode (no user interaction or display)
/passive   Unattended mode (progress bar only)
...
```